# Defining model to reduce overfitting effect of batch normalization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, batch-normalization

I'm trying to train my model using transfer learning from pretrained model with 30 classes and 7200 images(80% train, 10% validation, 10% test). My model is always overfitting despite changing various parameters. After i read this link https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#create_the_base_model_from_the_pre-trained_convnets, i know batch normalization always update variance even though the convolutional base was freeze.

So, i set `training = false` in base_model. But, i'm still confused. Is my code correct? Because my image was augmented using `ImageDataGenerator` not like example where augmentation and preprocessing used as base model input.

This is my code

```
#Create the model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense((len(CLASS_NAMES)), activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

history = model.fit_generator(train_data_gen,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(total_train / float(BATCH_SIZE))),
                              validation_data=val_data_gen,
                              validation_steps=int(np.ceil(total_val / float(BATCH_SIZE))),
                              callbacks=[cm_callback,tensorboard_callback])
```

Output

```
576/576 [==============================] - 157s 273ms/step - loss: 0.0075 - accuracy: 0.9996
144/144 [==============================] - 26s 181ms/step - loss: 0.0092 - accuracy: 1.0000

[0.007482105916197825, 0.99956596]
[0.009182391463279297, 1.0]
```

If my code is correct, Is it good that the validation accuracy = 1(too accurate)?

Comment: Always divide your dataset into three sets. Train set to train on, validation set to tune your hyperparameters, and finally a test set to test your model. If you have good training as well as validation accuracy but the model performs poorly on test set. It means your model is not working and you have to start from scratch. Do not attempt to tune the same model to increase accuracy on the test set as it will defeat the purpose of the test set.

Comment: @AniketBote so there is no problem with my code?

Comment: Its pretty simple code so I don't think anything is wrong. But try the above method. If there is vast difference between your validation accuracy and test accuracy then something is wrong.